# Помогите с программированием (Python)

Tags: python, математика

[image: Задание]

Не знаю, как написать / дописать (исправить) код.

Вот, все что есть на данный момент

```
import math

x = int(input("input X"))

if x <= 0:
    y = (1 + (math.fabs(x)) ** (0,5)
    print (y)
else:
    y = 1 + 3 * x / (1 + x**(1/3)) + 2
    print (y)
```

Comment: А в результате что хотите? Просто получить решение здесь и сейчас и дальше забыть про python или изучить и научиться? Если второй вариант то покажите как пытались решить (код вашего варианта решения в вопрос в текстовом виде) опишите сложности которые возникли, думаю что в таком варианте Вам охотно здесь помогут. Если первый вариант то Вы не по адресу.

Comment: import math
x=int(input("input X"))
if x<=0:
y=(1+(math.fabs(x)) ** (0,5)
print (y)
else:
y=1+3*x/(1+x**(1/3))+2
print (y)

Вот, все что есть на данный момент

Comment: Во второй части числитель, знаменатель и подкоренное выражение в знаменателе нужно в скобки взять, тогда правильно должно считаться.

Comment: `y = (1 + (math.fabs(x)) ** (0,5)` не хватает закрывающей скобки вот тут `x))` должно быть так `x)))` ну или, что совсем правильно будет то так `(1 + math.fabs(x)) ** 0.5` а тут `(0.5)` скобки не нужны совсем а запятую смените на точку. Ну и кометарий от @insolor тоже учтите

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
x = int(input("input X"))

if x <= 0:
    y = (1 + abs(x)) ** 0.5
    print (y)
else:
    y = (1 + 3*x) / ((1 + x)**(1/3) + 2)
    print (y)
```

Answer (score 4):

1. Разделитель дробной части точка, а не запятая.
2. В первой ветке ты про приоритеты операций подумал, а во второй - совсем нет.
3. Одна скобка непарная.